# Get percentage with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two price inputs. A normal price, and a cheaper.

I type in the normal price, like 15900, and I want to add a 10% discount of that price.

So I type in 10 to the `#akcios_onkeyup` input.

With this code, I only get `NaN`. What am I doing wrong?

```
<tr class="form-element form-element-text">
  <td class="label-col">Normal price: </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="termek_normal_ar" id="termek_normal_ar" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["termek_normal_ar"])?$_POST["termek_normal_ar"]:""; ?>" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="form-element form-element-text">
  <td class="label-col">Cheaper price: </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="termek_akcios_ar" id="termek_akcios_ar" 
           value="<?php echo isset($_POST["termek_akcios_ar"])?$_POST["termek_akcios_ar"]:""; ?>" />
    <span style="margin:0 10px;">or</span>
    <input type="text"  id="akcios_onkeyup" > % discount
  </td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#akcios_onkeyup').on('keyup', function()
                            {    
      var szazalek = $('#akcios_onkeyup').val();
      var osszeg = ($('#termek_normal_ar') - ( $('#termek_normal_ar') * szazalek / 100 ));
      $('#termek_akcios_ar').val(osszeg);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your forgot some `.val()`'s in your script - you are trying to do math with jquery collection objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your script with below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#akcios_onkeyup').on('keyup', function()
                            {    
      var szazalek = +$('#akcios_onkeyup').val();
      var osszeg = (+$('#termek_normal_ar').val() - ( +$('#termek_normal_ar').val() * szazalek / 100 ));
      $('#termek_akcios_ar').val(Math.round(osszeg));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, that works. How can i round the price? Beacause sometimes i get 1054.1, or 931.2

Comment: you can use Math.round(osszeg) I have updated this code with Math.round()

Comment: if this is helpful Please accept answers for others to refer. Thanks.